# Unit Test Mutually Authenticated ASP.Net Webservice

Tags: iis, ssl, client, mstest

I intended to test an ASP.Net webservice under IIS using the test facilities offered by Visual Studio. I have jumped many hurdles to get to the point where, had the requirements just called for server authentication, everything would have been fine. However, mutual authentication is required. When I set the web service to require a client certificate, the test emits the error message:

> The test adapter 'WebHostAdapter' threw an exception while running test 'GetDetails'. The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. The server may not be running a version of Asp.Net version 2.0 or greated. Requesting "https://localhost/pcoombes/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd" returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I am presuming that this is because the UrlToTest now requires a client certificate. Is there a client certificate attribute one can use? 
I am using VS 2008 and IIS 5.1

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication ? Was there a reason you were using VS2008 and IIS 5.1 in 2012?

Comment: On your server, you need to already have trusted your client's certificate. On the client, you also need to have your certificate and it's private key imported into the LocalMachine "My" or "Personal" certificate store and setup your web.config of your client app and tell it to use clientCredentialType="Certificate" under the bindings. Lookup WCF bindings to see examples.